# Novell eDirectory: Error while adding replica on new server

Tags: novell, edirectory

I want to add a replica of our whole eDirectory tree to a new server (OES11.2 SLES11.3).
So I wanted to do so via iManager. (Partitions and Replicas / Replica View / Add Replica)
Everthing looks normal. I see our other servers with added replicas and of course the server with the master image.
For addition information: I did that a lot of times without problems until now.

When I want to add a replica to the new server, i get the following error: (Error -636) The server is unreachable.

I checked the /etc/hosts file and the network settings on both servers.
Ndsrepair looks normal too. All servers are in sync and there are no connection errors. The replica depth of the new server is -1. I get that, because there is no replica on it yet.

But if i can connect from one server to another and there are no error messages, why does adding a replica not work?

I also tried to make a LAN trace, but didn't get any information that would help me out here. In the trace the communication seems normal!

Am I forgetting something here?

Every server in our environment runs OES11.2 except the master server which runs OES11.1

Thanks for your help!

Daniel

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong.

**Error -636** means that the replica is not **yet** available at the new server. When will the synchronization, the replica will be ready and available. Depending on the size of the Tree and the communication channel we can wait for up to some hours.